# What is @OpenWithToastLogo.png?

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, png

I copy-n-pasted some text from Notepad into a command line window. The copied text included a tab character prefixing the text I copied, for example "{tab}test.exe". When I pasted this into the command line, the result was:

```
@OpenWithToastLogo.pngtest.exe
```

Wait, what?

A quick search on the computer in question as well as a subsequent one on Google revealed the following:

- On the computer in question, there is in fact a file named `@OpenWithToastLogo.png` located in the Windows System32 folder.
- On Google, my scan of the search results seemed to show only non-specific answers (as of the writing of this question, that is) with the standard bevy of "is this malware" sites indicating that a virus scan showed the file *not* to be a virus.

What is the purpose of the `@OpenWithToastLogo.png` file?

Also, why is "@OpenWithToastLogo.png" (text) associated with a pasted tab character in a command line window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: Is it *really* `.png`? `Tab` trigger autocompletion.

Comment: @DanielB: Ah, yes, auto-complete. That definitively answers Question #2 (above). The TAB character is being interpreted as auto-complete, which in this case returns the first file in the current folder of the command window.

Comment: Can you open the file in an image viewer? I'm curious what its contents are. "Toast" I know is used to describe the pop-up messages that appear over the UI in Android (usually when a task is complete), it's probably something similar for Windows 8.

Comment: Toast is a video capture program. Do you have any Roxio products installed? If you really want to know where it came from, run Orca against c:\windows\installer to list all files associated with each installer.

Comment: It is a 32 x 32 png file.... Black. Hope that is enough. It has no use... maybe a message to someone.

Comment: Possibly related? http://superuser.com/questions/792607/why-does-windows-think-that-my-wireless-keyboard-is-a-toaster

Comment: Including an answer within the question makes it difficult for others to find it in a search.  Instead, please post the answer as an answer (read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer))

Comment: It seems to match up with @TileEmpty1x1Image.png